# Do I need to show my own attempt if I post a question along with an answer written by me?

Tags: discussion, support

> Do I need to show my own attempt if I post a question along with an
>   answer written by me?

1. Suppose I come across a remarkably good question on a particular chemistry topic and wish to share it with the community and if feel that future viewers might find it useful should I post it here along with the answer? (Stack Exchange allows it.)
2. Moreover in such a case do I need to show my attempt in the question part (like we do for questions we want others to answer)?

One plus point of this approach is that I too will be able to find the question along with the answer sometime in the future in case I need, with a simple google search. I know I can make a blog or something but I feel Chemistry Stack Exchange constitutes one of the top Google Search results on Chemistry. Also the LaTeX works excellently here.

Comment: (2) I don't think so, and (1) in any case I encourage you to do so, as the chem.SE community has consciously been more receptive to keeping questions that are of the type you mention alive (and not closing them). [Here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58727/chirality-of-substituted-adamantanes) is a recent example of one person asking and answering a rather good question. My $0.02.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Thank you for your $0.02 :-).

Comment: I also think that it's fine. I agree with jonsca, that you should try to make your questions about the concept involved and not only about the solution of an particular exercise. Please be aware that the community will have the final say in the matter and might disagree with what you find interesting. All in all I find this a good idea and welcome the enthusiasm.

Comment: @Todd [My first edition of the question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/58727/1) was a little tongue-in-cheek. ;)

Comment: @orthocresol - Nice Easter Egg, sorry I missed it the first time around!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's no need to show your attempt in the body of the question in such a case.  This is definitely not the type of scenario that the homework policy is trying to guard against, since an appropriately matched question/answer/reference would be of great value to future users.

The *best* thing to do in this situation is to make the question more conceptual in nature rather than a specific exercise or example, but I don't think a question consisting of a rote exercise what you had in mind anyway!

Comment: +1 I do not think that it is necessary. Even though I am the author of the linked question in the comments. It was more for fun than anything.

Comment: I didn't even think to look for it!