# Do we need a separate [proofreading] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

If a user includes the following in a question:

- attempt to provide an answer to own question;
- code for debugging;
- own unique view towards the problem;
- a request to check whether her/his assumptions are correct,

is there a need for a [proofreading](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofreading) tag, or anything similar (e.g.
 [peer-review](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peer-review), [debugging](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging))? It was a recent question [I made a Flowchart for Sig Figs- Is it Correct?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83325/i-made-a-flowchart-for-sig-figs-is-it-correct) and several earlier requests for debugging non-working Gaussian code that made me think of this suggestion.

Comment: There's already similar tag [tag:erratum] not exactly common though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's quite a meta tag... I'm not sure whether this is a great idea.

The biggest trouble I have is that quite a few of these questions would probably be off-topic. For example, the check-my-work / [amirite](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3396/4945) questions are not really well fitted for our format. Code (like actual program code) for debugging should probably better go to Stack Overflow, Code Review, or similar. Chemistry.se is not a place where we do genuine research, so peer-review is probably also not our forte. Apart from that I fail to see how this tag would add anything to the question. The same applies to questions that want to know whether the made assumptions are correct. I think in those cases the question itself would be clear enough that a tag like this is superfluous.
While I have no objection of debugging electronic structure program's inputs,<sup>[1]</sup> I fear that the level of these questions are strongly dependent on the problem at hand, especially if the asker might use a completely unfitting methodology. (I have seen too many researchgate questions about Gaussian errors, that with a thorough Google search could be resolved.) On the other hand there are legit problems, that are not yet covered. In those cases I think such a tag would be misplaced, as it essentially boils down to a methodology question.

While writing this, I'd have to conclude, that **I am against such a tag**.

<sup>[1]</sup> I am aware that I still have not drafted the long planned guidelines for such questions.

Comment: And also, have we reached a consensus on amirite yet? (Other than that nobody likes them)

Comment: @Jan I think that's the current state, since we have (temporarily) abandoned to fix the homework close reason, there has not been any progress in that regard either.

Answer (score 5):

**I think this, if anything, should be embodied as a newly created, dedicated chatroom, instead of as a new tag.**

I have seen the horror that is the meta-tag, and I recoil aghast at the prospect of creating another.

However, the purpose-specific [Spring Cleaning chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55978/spring-cleaning) has served its purpose well, and leaves both the main and meta sites un-muddied. Tracking and cleaning up posts needing proofreading would be something needing only momentary tracking; once a post is dealt with, there'd be no need to follow it any longer.

*(Upon rereading the original question, I may have misunderstood the point of it. Apologies if so.)*

Comment: You'd need a team of dedicated volunteers for that...

Comment: I misread it similarly, and I'd say that people are already good about cleaning up stuff that needs to be cleaned up.